# eAccelerator.dll missing in XAMPP Version: 5.6.3

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, eaccelerator

Good afternoon together,
i tried to enable eAccelerator extension within my php.ini , but im getting the message:
" Failed to load C:\xampp\php\ext\php_eaccelerator.dll".

I tried to find the dll on google, but didn't get results for my php version: 5.6.3 .

I am using Windows 8.1. Where can i download the eAccelerator.dll to speed up the php application? (I am using symfony and it is a bit slow on my computer).

Regards and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile eaccelerator extension with PHP 5.6.3 currently it is not coming with xampp latest version.....

Try http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php