# Failed loading php_eaccelerator_ts.dll in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-5.4

I am beginner in LARAVEL. I got error 'failed loading php_eaccelerator_ts.dll' when I tried to install LARAVEL using command prompt in windows7.

My PHP version is 5.6 & used xampp server.

Would you please give me proper suggestion about it.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just search the error on Google and you get a few results, even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460041/eaccelerator-dll-missing-in-xampp-version-5-6-3) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566822/xampp-missing-php-eaccelerator-ts-dll). Are both not answering your question?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan  I have already used both answers but it doesn't working here